# Microsoft Band Web Tile Not Refreshing

Tags: microsoft-band

This post is similar to [Microsoft Band Web Tile not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466328/microsoft-band-web-tile-not-updating), but the response marked as an answer to that question didn't really solve my issue, so I thought I'd start a new post.

I recently purchased a Band 2 and am trying to set up a web tile that will pull data from a service that provides data in JSON format (not an rss feed). So, I created a single-page non-feed tile using the 5-step authoring tool. When I first deployed the tile to my band, it successfully polled the service and displayed data; however, since that point, the data displayed on the web tile has not updated, even though the refresh interval is set (the default of 30 minutes).

The service that's being called is an ASP.Net Web API service. It is setting the following cache-related headers:

Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Last-Modified: 
ETag:

If I review the HTTP logs for the site, I can see where my service endpoint is getting called from my band/phone, roughly every 30 minutes, and the server responds with a 200 OK response on every call - I'm not seeing a 304 Not Modified response on the server side of the transaction.

My band is paired with an Android device (Samsung GS5). I've also tried pairing with an iPhone 6, as well, with the same result. Other tiles on the band seem to work fine (i.e., the standard ones that come with the MS Health app). as part of pairing/re-pairing, I've done a factory reset twice, and that didn't seem to help. I've tried re-starting both phones (when they were paired), as well. That doesn't help, either.

What am I missing?

For reference, here is what the web tile's manifest.json file contains (with placeholders for some data points:

```
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "name": "<Name Here>",
  "description": "<Description here>",
  "version": 1,
  "versionString": "1",
  "author": "<Author Here>",
  "organization": "",
  "contactEmail": "",
  "tileIcon": {
    "46": "icons/tileIcon.png"
  },
  "icons": {},
  "refreshIntervalMinutes": 30,
  "resources": [
    {
      "url": "<URL Here>",
      "style": "Simple",
      "content": {
        "_1_bg": "BG",
        "_1_datestring": "DateString",
        "_1_trend": "Trend",
        "_1_direction": "Direction"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pages": [
    {
      "layout": "MSBand_MetricsWithIcons",
      "condition": "true",
      "textBindings": [
        {
          "elementId": "12",
          "value": "BG: {{_1_bg}}"
        },
        {
          "elementId": "22",
          "value": "{{_1_datestring}}"
        },
        {
          "elementId": "32",
          "value": "Trend: {{_1_trend}}, {{_1_direction}}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "notifications": [
    {
      "condition": "{{_1_bg}} >= 250",
      "title": "HIGH BG: {{_1_bg}}",
      "body": "{{_1_datestring}}"
    },
    {
      "condition": "{{_1_bg}} <= 80",
      "title": "Low BG: {{_1_bg}}",
      "body": "{{_1_datestring}}"
    },
    {
      "condition": "{{_1_bg}} <= 55",
      "title": "REALLY LOW: {{_1_bg}}",
      "body": "{{_1_datestring}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you supply the URL for the resource? If so I can take a look at your server responses and see why the tile is not refreshing.

Better yet, can you share the webtile and I can try that to see why it is not refreshing. You can build your WebTile at https://developer.microsofthealth.com/WebTile/ and choose to submit it. Reply here with the name of it and I will take a look.

By the way, here is how we handle refresh on a simple tile:

1. If Etag was in the last response then use that with next request to let the server decide if there is something new to provide.
2. If Etag was not supplied, then look for Last-Modified and use that when available.
3. Else, process the downloaded data and send to the tile.

So, if you have Etag or Last-Modified in your server responses then we will use that to send in future requests and that may be causing your problem. In that case you would want to make sure that Etag and Last-Modified are not being sent in your server responses.

Comment: It looks like part of my post related to the Last-Modified and ETag header got modified when I submitted - the service is actually setting values for these; the Last-Modified date is getting reset on every call to the service. The ETag is a Guid (cast to a string) that is re-generated on every call, so should, in theory, never be the same as the previous request.

Comment: The initial version of the service did not provide either the Last-Modified or ETag values. I added them after doing some initial testing without them, and not getting the data refreshed on the band. Here's the URL for the service: https://sfowlerbanddata.azurewebsites.net/api/sgv/latest

Comment: I have polled https://sfowlerbanddata.azurewebsites.net/api/sgv/latest multiple times and I am seeing that the values are changing and the tile is changing.

Is your tile updating now?

I also created a sample tile like the one you created using the Web Authoring tool and it is updating as expected on iOS.

Comment: Joe: I just used the Fiddler app (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to query your server at http://50.63.66.52:4957/ and it is returning updated data. You should open a new question with a link to your webtile to explain what problem you are running into.

Comment: No, it's not updating at this point, either. I think I'm going to uninstall/reinstall MS Health on the phone, reset the band to factory settings and then try it all over again... I created the web tile using the same https://developer.microsofthealth.com/WebTile/ you mentioned in your post; there's nothing real special about it.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I can think of:

- Are you keeping the tile open on your WebTile while the updates are happening? If so, then tiles in some FW versions of the band do not update when new data comes in, close the tile and open it after the sync.
- You can test your tile syncing more often than 30 minutes by hitting the sync icon on the top left of the left nav bar inside the Microsoft Health app.

After that, if you are still having problems please send feedback from inside the Microsoft Health app. Access via Left Nav, bottom under Settings, use the "Help and Feedback".

When reporting feedback, if you can attach the webtile that will help us test the webtile you are having problems with.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mark... I've still got a non-updating tile, but the attempt at assistance has been appreciated... To respond to your latest points: no, I don't keep the tile open. I access the tile and check for an update and always exit right back out. Also, I've tried using the sync icon, and it doesn't refresh the tile, either. I've submitted feedback using the MS Health app as suggested, though I didn't see a way to attach the tile (I could do an image, but that was it). Is there a way to edit the submission now that it has been entered?

Comment: There is no way to edit the submission once it is entered, sorry. Submit the WebTile with the "Publish WebTile" option at the end of the WebTile Authoring tool. Include your name in the Author and I will have a look.

Comment: Mark, thanks again... Sorry for the delay in responding, but I've been out of town and unable to work on this for a bit. I just uploaded my web tile to the gallery... I'm not real sure I like doing that, but it is what it is... How does one get a tile removed from the gallery once it is uploaded? I don't necessarily want this one to hang around out there.

Comment: Ok, after giving the gallery a few days to update, I confirmed that my tile is in the gallery (Simple BG is the name). I recently updated my phone to the latest available updates (Samsung SG5 on AT&T), reset my Band to factory settings, uninstalled and re-installed Microsoft Health, re--added the band, and went to the gallery and installed the tile from there. After the initial install, I got the message indicating there was no data, so I manually synched via MS Health. That did an update. I waited almost an hour with no auto-update, tried manual update, still no update to info display.

Comment: At this point, I think I'm ready to give up on the Band experiment and just go back to my Pebble, which is frustrating, because I'm generally very pro-Microsoft. I've been a developer for 20 years, and having something like this that should be dead simple not work is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I share the frustration here. I too have exactly the same issue it seems. I have also been a developer for 20 years. My answer to this problem now is that there is a bug perhaps when JSON is used, and/or with Android phones. I've tried to get answers and discussions with Microsoft but not had any luck. My issue is at [Web Tile works once but never refreshes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838182/web-tile-works-once-but-never-refreshes)

Comment: Well, I was going to swallow my frustration after seeing the reply on your thread from Mark Thistle indicating that they had found the problem and were putting the fix in the next health app refresh... Unfortunately, that refresh didn't fix the problem I'm having with my webtile. Extremely disappointing... Anyone want a Band 2, barely used?