# Web Tile works once but never refreshes

Tags: microsoft-band

I have developed a one page web tile using the online tool. The URL returns JSON from my own service. The first time the tile runs the data is correct on the band, after that though it never ever refreshes. I have looked into the forums and tried things out, including refreshing with the sync on the phone and ensuring the tile is closed. The headers on my service do not include Last-Modified or ETag as suggested in forums. Doing a post in the browser on my phone and desktop works like it should with the latest data.

My request headers look like this:

**Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6**

My response headers look like this:

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 17 Jan 2016 11:56:27 GMT
Server: localhost**

Comment: Just to add to this, you can see the requests coming into my service from my phone, so it definitely calls it when you sync from Health app and when it does it automatically. What it is not doing is actually refreshing that data it gets.

Comment: So still no further with this after troubelshooting it for many hours. I've even created a new service to return JSON so now I have both a python service on raspberry pi and an IIS web api service on a Win server. The problem is exactly the same on the band with both services. The first time it installs, it gets the data, after that, never updates but makes the call to the service. This must be a bug, anyone got any ideas here?

Comment: Aother update. There are other web tiles that return JSON from the 'Community Tiles' web site that do exactly the same and never update after the first installation. I've tried just about everything now. My theory is that my phone is Android and that might be the problem. Can anyone please try this out or give me some thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. We have identified the problem in the Simple tiles on Android and are working on a fix. We are targeting to have it in the next Android Health App refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm for me using my Android phone and the latest version of MS Health (1.3.20213.1) and MS Band (2.0.4215.0 26 R), my web tile now works, so this was indeed a bug, nothing to do with my own web tile.